# jQueryUI disable / cancel icon from being dragged in a sortable list?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am having difficulty trying to disable the list elements from being dragged by the icon.

Each li has an icon, when clicked either removes or adds it into another list. However if you drag by its icon it removes or adds the item.

I want to be able to drag the li around, but stop the icons from being dragable on the li's.

I have a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/27/

I have tried a number of things with no success and I cant figure it out: -

```
    $( "#gallery li" ).draggable({
          cancel: "a.ui-icon",
          revert: "invalid",
          containment: "document",
          helper: "clone",
          cursor: "move"
        });
    $( ".ui-icon" ).disableSelection();

    //Get Dropped Item
    $("#trash").droppable({
         drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).stop();

               }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, I added the following:

```
$('.delete, .add').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This stops the mousedown event from bubbling up, so it inhibits the draggable behaviour, when the icon (an `a` element inside the `li`) is clicked.

HOWEVER, this is not a good solution! It adds event handlers to the `a` elements themselves, so it only adds handlers to the elements which exist when you call `on`. If you add a new item (I used the ADD button, luckily it was implemented), the fix *doesn't apply*. You would have to add the handler to any new items that are added.

---

We could do it a better way. We could add a handler to the containers instead:

```
$('#gallery, #trash').on('mousedown', '.ui-icon', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The second argument of `on` lets us specify a filter. The `#gallery` and `#trash` elements can receive `mousedown` events bubbling up from child elements, but we only want this handler to execute if the event originated from a `.ui-icon`. This is pretty good, we only have to set up event handlers once and there's only one per sortable container, so it's easier and more efficient.

---

I decided to check the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel), and found that there's a specific option to deal with this:

```
$("#gallery, #trash").sortable("option", "cancel", ".ui-icon");
```

which very cleanly tells the `sortable` widget not to allow sorting if it's started from a `.ui-icon`! Instead of calling sortable("option") explicitly, you could add this option to the initialization of your sortables.

Comment: Having looked at the fiddle and trying to implement the code of $("#gallery, #trash").sortable("option", "cancel", ".ui-icon"); I cant get it working either? Did you manage to get the fiddle working?

Comment: @John yeah that line works in the fiddle, as long as you add it after the .sortable() initialization. Another way is to just add it as an initialization option. See that working here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/56/